# If-else statement to count some variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help to solved this algorithm problem with How a Person is popular in his city.

**My situation**

How the algorithm should work like
If a person "mark" has 500 friends in his city out of 500,000.

```
(500/500,000)*50,000 = 5
```

So `5` in `50,000` people Know him right.

But When  friends count increase the 50,000 should decrease

> If "sam" has 1000 friends then

```
(1000/500,000)*25000 = 5
```

So `5` in `25000` people know his name

Yes we could implement this in `if/else` condition 
If so then i have to write 500 lines of code.

Is there another way to do this in PHP?

```
<?php 
    $totalfriends = 100; 
    $totali = 5000000;
    $name = "Sam";


    if ($totalfriends >= 100 && $totalfriends <= 499 ) {
     $r = ($totalfriends/$totali)*50000;
    echo  round($r),' ',"in 50K People on City regonize this Profile";
    }else if ($totalfriends >= 500 && $totalfriends <= 999) {
    $r = ($totalfriends/$totali)*25000;
    echo  round($r),' ',"in 25K People on City know".$name;
    }else{
  echo "";
 }
?>
```

Comment: You should start reading more about php and programming in general. I am afraid you don't even understand the basic data structures (arrays) and control structures (while loop, do loop, etc.). Read more about programming prior to ask.

Comment: @MayankVadiya I don't have any code.I have some Bunch of PHP if/else staments.Just GIve me a idea how to implement in For loop.OR i have to post my if/else statements

Comment: Post your code, **or rather a sample of your code** Then we can see what we are dealsing with and make suggestion. Otherwise we cannot help as the question as written does not really describe in wnough detail what you are actually dealing with. **PS** Add code to your question with an edit!

Comment: You should be doing that filtering in the database, not in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
foreach([100, 500, 543, 1000, 5000, 51000, 500000] as $my_friends)
   echo '5 in '. getScoreOf($my_friends) . "<br>";

function getScoreOf($my_friends){
   $of = 5;
   $total = 5e5; //that's 500,000 ;)
   $step = 100; //minimum step, so output is not "4604" but "4600"
   $out_of = $total / $my_friends * $of;
   return $out_of > $step? round($out_of / $step) * $step: round($out_of);
}
```

---

[run it in sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f78ea6cc1f86ce2cc9a4a61efbd258baab8d8bde)

---

edit: solution merged with original code

```
<?php
$of = 5;
$totalfriends = 100; 
$name = "Sam";
echo $of ." in ". getScoreOf($of, $totalfriends) ." people in city know ". $name;

function getScoreOf($of, $my_friends){
   $total = 5e6; //that's 5,000,000 ;)
   $step = 100; //minimum step, so output is not "4604" but "4600"
   $out_of = $total / $my_friends * $of;
   return $out_of > $step? round($out_of / $step) * $step: round($out_of);
}
```

Comment: Eventhough more downvotes thanx for your reply man ! Exactly it is working But I need only single output.

Comment: only single output? use getScoreOf function where you need it, do not use the "foreach" :) foreach is there only for testing purpose ;)

Comment: I've edited my answer, so you can see real usage with your code. Accepting the answer is well enough, glad to help.

Comment: It is working.You know I am new to PHP Can you please explain this Line   `$out_of > $step? round($out_of / $step) * $step: round($out_of);`

Comment: this is ternary operator and $res=($out_of > $step ? round($out_of / $step) * $step : round($out_of)); echo $res; @Bajwakapoor

Comment: @Bajwakapoor ternary is like "condition? if_condition_is_true: if_condition_is_false". In this case: if you have so many friends, that your score would be lesser then step, step is ignored. So you can get rank of "5 in 10". Without checking $out_of > $step, you would get "5 in 100".